# CSRF token missing or incorrect - using auto-complete light in Django

Tags: django, ajax, forms, csrf

Running into CSRF_Token missing or incorrect in my Django-app, don't really understand what the issue is as I've included the {% csrf_token %} in any possible form being rendered by my template. I suspect it may have to do with the ajax requests that are done within the form to retrieve area-names and more, maybe someone can tell me what the issue is. I'm using autocomplete-light for retrieving some data from my DB, don't know if that can play a part in this. I've tried searching around online but haven't found a solution that seems to apply to my problem.

Views.py

```
Class BreedAutocomplete(autocomplete.Select2QuerySetView):

    def get_queryset(self):

        if not self.request.user.is_authenticated:
            return DogBreeds.objects.none()

        qs = DogBreeds.objects.all()

        if self.q:
            qs = qs.filter(name__istartswith=self.q)

        return qs


class AdListTakeMyDog(generic.ListView):
    model = Advertisement
    context_object_name = 'ads'
    template_name = 'core/advertisement_list_take.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Advertisement.objects.filter(is_offering_own_dog=True)
        return queryset


class AdListGetMeADog(generic.ListView):
    model = Advertisement
    context_object_name = 'ads'
    template_name = 'core/advertisement_list_get.html'

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = Advertisement.objects.filter(is_offering_own_dog=False)
        return queryset


class NewAdTakeMyDog(CreateView):
    model = Advertisement
    form_class = NewAdTakeMyDogForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('view_ads_take_my_dog')
    template_name = 'core/advertisement_form_take.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.is_offering_own_dog = True
        return super().form_valid(form)


class NewAdGetMeADog(CreateView):
    model = Advertisement
    form_class = NewAdGetMeADogForm
    success_url = reverse_lazy('ad_changelist')
    template_name = 'core/advertisement_form_get.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        form.instance.author = self.request.user
        form.instance.is_offering_own_dog = False
        return super().form_valid(form)
```

advertisement_create - TEMPLATE

```
{% extends '_base.html' %}

{% load static %}

{% block content %}
  <body onload="hide_area_field()">
    

  {% block form_title %}
  <h2>Ny annons</h2>
  {% endblock form_title %}

      
  {% if form.is_multipart %}
    <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="adForm" data-municipalities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_municipalities' %}" data-areas-url="{% url 'ajax_load_areas' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}  

  {% else %}
    <form method="post" id="adForm" data-municipalities-url="{% url 'ajax_load_municipalities' %}" data-areas-url="{% url 'ajax_load_areas' %}" novalidate>
    {% csrf_token %}  
    
    {% endif %}
      

    <table>  
      {{ form.as_p }}
    </table>

    <button type="submit">Publicera annons</button>

  {{ form.media }}

  </form>

</body>
{% endblock content %}

{% block footer %}

  {% comment %} Imports for managing Django Autocomplete Light in form {% endcomment %}
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/select2.css' %}" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/jquery.init.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/autocomplete.init.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/select2.js' %}"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/css/select2.css' %}" />
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/vendor/select2/dist/js/select2.full.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'autocomplete_light/forward.js' %}"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="{% static 'admin/js/vendor/jquery/jquery.js' %}"></script>




  {% comment %} Functions for handling area selectors {% endcomment %}
  <script>
      function hide_area_field() {
        const area_selector = document.getElementById('id_area');
        area_selector.style.display = 'none';
      }

      /* Get URL for requesting list of municipalities & Areas */
      const baseURI = window.location.origin
      const municipality_url = document.getElementById('adForm')['attributes']['data-municipalities-url']['value']
      const area_url = document.getElementById('adForm')['attributes']['data-areas-url']['value']


      /* Get relevant objects from DOM */
      const province_selector = document.getElementById('id_province');
      const municipality_selector = document.getElementById('id_municipality');
      const area_selector = document.getElementById('id_area');

      /* Update municipalities when Province have been chosen */
      province_selector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
        
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

        xhr.onload = function () {
          if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
              if (xhr.status === 200) {
                  municipality_selector.innerHTML = xhr.response
              }
          }
        };

        xhr.open('GET',  baseURI + municipality_url, true);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('province', province_selector.value)
        xhr.send();

      });


      /* Update Areas when Municipiality have been chosen */
      municipality_selector.addEventListener('change', (event) => {
      
      var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

      xhr.onload = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === xhr.DONE) {
            if (xhr.status === 200) {
                if (xhr.response.length > 58) {
                  area_selector.style.display = ''
                  area_selector.innerHTML = xhr.response
                } else {
                  area_selector.style.display = 'none'
                }
            }
        }
      };

      xhr.open('GET',  baseURI + area_url, true);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('municipality', municipality_selector.value)
      xhr.send();

    });
  </script>

{% endblock footer %}
```

forms.py

```
class NewAdTakeMyDogForm(forms.ModelForm):

    breed = forms.ModelChoiceField(
        queryset=DogBreeds.objects.all(),
        widget=autocomplete.ModelSelect2(url='breed-autocomplete')
    )

    class Meta:
        model = Advertisement
        fields = ('province', 'municipality', 'area', 'title', 'description', 'days_per_week', 'size_offered', 'breed', 'image1', 'image2', 'image3')

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(NewAdTakeMyDogForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['municipality'].queryset = Municipality.objects.none()
        self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.none()
        self.fields['area'].required = False

        if 'province' in self.data:
            try:
                # Set municipality queryset
                province_id = int(self.data.get('province'))
                self.fields['municipality'].queryset = Municipality.objects.filter(province_id=province_id).order_by('name')
            
                # Set area queryset
                municipality_id = int(self.data.get('municipality'))
                self.fields['area'].queryset = Area.objects.filter(municipality_id=municipality_id).order_by('name')
                

            except (ValueError, TypeError):
                pass # invalid input from the client; ignore and fallback to empty Municipality/Area queryset
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error was that I was looking at the wrong template, I have multiple template with inheritance, and had got them mixed up, so I though I was presenting a CSRF token in the form, but it was done in a template that wasn't used. Lesson learned - have one BASE template which you start from and only use blocks for essential code that changes between the base-template.

Answer (score 1):

Your AJAX request doesn't contain the CSRF token. So Django's cross site request forgery protection kicks in.

Django [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/csrf/#ajax)
explains in detail how to acquire the CSRF token when you send an AJAX POST request and how to include it in the headers of your request.

Comment: Both of my AJAX requests are GET requests, which should be fine, can't seem to see which one is triggering the CSRF